# Makefile with generated C++ source files

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I'm working with a tool that generates C++ source files that I need to include in my C++ project compilation.

To extraordinarily simplify things, my one non-generated source file, `main.cpp`, is as follows:

```
extern void bar();

int main(int, char**)
{
    bar();
    return 0;
}
```

And my `Makefile` is below. The overall structure is what's already existing in our project, and I'm simply adding in the parts noted to generate the needed source file `bar.cpp` and makefile `bar.mk`, which adds `bar.cpp` to the `SRCS` variable so it (I wish) gets included in the compilation:

```
SRCS := $(CURDIR)/main.cpp

#################### Adding everything between here... #####
BAR_MK := bar.mk

ifeq (,$(findstring clean,$(MAKECMDGOALS)))
include $(BAR_MK)
endif
#################### ...and here ###########################

OBJ_DIR := $(CURDIR)/obj
OBJS := $(patsubst %.cpp,%.o,$(subst $(CURDIR),$(OBJ_DIR),$(SRCS)))

a.out: $(OBJS)
        @echo OBJS == $(OBJS)
        @echo SRCS == $(SRCS)
        $(CXX) $(OBJS)

#################### Adding everything between here... #####
GEN_DIR := $(CURDIR)/gen

# "Generate" my source file(s), add them to SRCS via an external makefile
$(BAR_MK): $(GEN_DIR)/bar.cpp
$(GEN_DIR)/bar.cpp:
        mkdir -p $(dir $@)
        echo "void bar () {}" > $@
        echo SRCS += $@ > $(BAR_MK)
#################### ...and here ###########################

$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: %.cpp
        mkdir -p $(dir $@)
        $(CXX) -c -o $@ $<

clean:
        rm -rf $(OBJ_DIR)
        rm -f a.out
        rm -rf $(GEN_DIR)
        rm -f $(BAR_MK)
```

The issue is, the compilation fails the first time I run `make` due to "undefined reference to `bar()`", but running `make` immediately afterward succeeds. This is because upon the first run of `make`, when it evaluates the `a.out:` rule, it sees `SRCS` as only containing `main.cpp`, and so `bar.cpp` doesn't get compiled. Then on the second (and subsequent) runs, `SRCS` contains both `main.cpp` and `bar.cpp`, so `bar.cpp` gets compiled that time.

This seems odd to me, because per the [GNU Make manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Remaking-Makefiles) on "How Makefiles Are Remade":

> After all makefiles have been checked, if any have actually been changed, make starts with a clean slate and reads all the makefiles over again.

So after GNU Make processes `include bar.mk` on my first `make` invocation, sees that it's out of date and builds it, I'd expect that it would then start over *from scratch* with parsing the Makefile from the start, including `bar.mk` and, in turn, having `SRCS` contain both `main.cpp` and `bar.cpp`.

Is my expectation wrong? Or is there something wrong with my (additions to the) Makefile? I'm using GNU Make 4.1 on Linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rule that has `bar.mk` as a target has no recipe. So make considers that there is no way to generate the missing `bar.mk`. But it does not fail immediately, it continues parsing the main Makefile, generates `bar.cpp`... and `bar.mk` but it had no way to know this in advance. The result is that `bar.mk` is generated but not included... and make does not fail. Not sure whether this should be considered as a bug or not. I filled a *maybe-a-bug* report.

Anyway, if you tell make explicitly how to build `bar.mk` it should work:

```
$(BAR_MK): $(GEN_DIR)/bar.cpp
        echo 'SRCS += $<' > $@

$(GEN_DIR)/bar.cpp:
        mkdir -p $(dir $@)
        echo "void bar () {}" > $@
```

**EDIT**: add some more comments / alternate solutions

Note that the `$(BAR_MK)` rule is still not perfect: it declares a prerequisite that is not a real one. But before removing it we must fix something else: your pattern rule will not match for the generated source file because of your use of `$(CURDIR)` that prepends the full path. Let's get rid of it:

```
SRCS := main.cpp
BAR_MK := bar.mk

ifeq (,$(findstring clean,$(MAKECMDGOALS)))
include $(BAR_MK)
endif

OBJ_DIR := obj
OBJS := $(patsubst %.cpp,$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o,$(SRCS))

a.out: $(OBJS)
    @echo OBJS == $(OBJS)
    @echo SRCS == $(SRCS)
    $(CXX) $(OBJS)

GEN_DIR := gen

$(BAR_MK):
    echo 'SRCS += $(GEN_DIR)/bar.cpp' > $@

$(GEN_DIR)/bar.cpp:
    mkdir -p $(dir $@)
    echo "void bar () {}" > $@

$(OBJ_DIR)/%.o: %.cpp
    mkdir -p $(dir $@)
    $(CXX) -c -o $@ $<

clean:
    rm -rf $(OBJ_DIR) a.out $(GEN_DIR) $(BAR_MK)
```

Finally, if you really want to generate both `bar.mk` and `gen/bar.cpp` with the same rule, there is one possibility, still telling make: [a pattern rule with multiple targets](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Pattern-Intro):

> Pattern rules may have more than one target. Unlike normal rules, this
>   does not act as many different rules with the same prerequisites and
>   recipe. If a pattern rule has multiple targets, make knows that the
>   rule’s recipe is responsible for making all of the targets. The recipe
>   is executed only once to make all the targets. When searching for a
>   pattern rule to match a target, the target patterns of a rule other
>   than the one that matches the target in need of a rule are incidental:
>   make worries only about giving a recipe and prerequisites to the file
>   presently in question. However, when this file’s recipe is run, the
>   other targets are marked as having been updated themselves.

In the following it is the `a` of `bar` that will match the pattern rule's wildcard:

```
PATTERN_TARGET := $(subst bar,b%r,$(BAR_MK) $(GEN_DIR)/bar.cpp)
$(PATTERN_TARGET):
    mkdir -p $(GEN_DIR)
    echo "void bar () {}" > $(GEN_DIR)/bar.cpp
    echo 'SRCS += $(GEN_DIR)/bar.cpp' > bar.mk
```

But this is probably too strange and would completely ruin maintainability. Prefer one of the two other options, they are easier to understand.

Comment: I guess you also want to add `bar.cpp` as an explicit prerequisite for the main target.

Comment: This shouldn't be necessary if the `bar.mk` file is correctly included. This is because `bar.mk`  adds `bar.cpp` to the `SRCS` variable. This should then be reflected in `OBJS` and everything should be OK.

Comment: But that still fails in the corner case when `bar.mk` does not yet exist.

Comment: No, because if `bar.mk` does not exist and there is a rule to create it, make executes the recipe, reads again all makefiles (including the newly created `bar.mk`) and restarts from scratch (see [the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Remaking-Makefiles))

Comment: Ah, interesting. I always just figured that even an empty recipe was still a recipe to (re)build something. I'll try and find if this is specified explicitly anywhere in the manual. Anyways, making this change here works and gives me the expected behavior (the Makefile gets parsed/executed twice). Thanks!

Comment: `OBJ_DIR` also uses the full path (from `CURDIR`), so the pattern rule does match `bar.cpp`

Comment: Not really: in the case of the generated source file the pattern is equivalent to `/absolute/path/obj/gen/bar.o: gen/bar.cpp` and you have no rule to generate `gen/bar.cpp`; the one you have is for `/absolute/path/gen/bar.cpp`. Give it a try and you will see...